# How to display image on jsp from DB using java servlet

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

What I am trying to do is basically to display image from Mysql on jsp page.
I was successfully able to call the blob image file into outputstream in my java servlet using the following code.

In servlet,

```
byte[] imgData = null;
Blob image1 = null;
image1 = result.getBlob("image1");
imgData = image1.getBytes(1, (int)image1.length());
```

In jsp,

```
<% 
response.setContentType("image/gif");
OutputStream o = response.getOutputStream();
o.write(imgData);
%>
```

The problem with this method is that this jsp page is fulfilled with the image.
That way, the page discards other contents and only displays the image.
What I want to do is to display few images using

```html
<img src=??? width=??? height=???>
```

I tried to resize output stream image, but I don't think there is a way.

Please help me

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should create two different servlets:

One for downloading an image by getting a writer from `HttpServlet` and writing byte array as a response.

Two, the `.jsp` page will contain an `img` tag which `src` will link to the first endpoint.

This will look something like:

1)

```
public class ImageServlet extends HttpServlet {
    //...
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        //...
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", this.getServletContext().getMimeType(imageFileName));
        response.setHeader("Content-Length", X);
        response.getOutputStream().write(<<image byte[]>>);
    }
```

2)

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
     prefix="c" %>
<html>
    <head><title>Hello</title></head>
    <body bgcolor="white">
        <img src="/images?id=3" height="Xpx" width="Ypx">
         <h2>My name is Duke. What is yours?</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

I think this should work. If the answer was helpful, vote as an accepted answer please.

Comment: I do not know the file name because i just saved into mysql DB. Also, I don't understand what it means by "The .jsp page will contain an img tag which src will link to the first endpoint.".

Comment: @JasonYang you can set a rule, that for image with index `z` in your DB table, the endpoint will be `/images?id=z`. When your servlet will get a request with param `id` which equals `z` you will search the DB for an image with index `z`. About your question, look at my example #2...